# Who is the person watching the auction in "Get Out"?

Tags: get-out

During the silent auction in "Get Out", there is a figure sitting at one of the round tables in the background.  They don't seem to be involved in the bidding but do appear to be watching the auction intently.  (I'm not talking about the art dealer's assistant, who is standing just behind the last row... this is someone who is further up the lawn.)  Who is that, and why aren't they in the bidding area with everyone else?

Comment: A screenshot would improve the question, I think. If you can fetch one off YouTube or something... :)

Comment: I think you are talking about Jeremy(acted by [Caleb Landry Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caleb_Landry_Jones) who is the brother of Rose. Check this [image](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/villains/images/8/82/Caleb-landry-jones-get-out-full-movie-gray-vest-13961476.jpeg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/214?cb=20170730222805)

Answer (score 6):

I believe commenter "J M" got it right.  It's consistent with it being Jeremy.

Here's a screenshot from the trailer:

[image]

Comment: I would add the image @JM used - really clinches it.